# How to add hex to char array?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have been programming a while but I am fairly new to C++. I am writing a program that takes an .exe and gets its hex and stores it in and unsigned char array. I can take in the .exe and return its hex fine. My problem is I am having trouble storing the hex in the correct format in the char array.

When I print the array it outputs the hex but I need to add 0x to the front.

Sample output: `04 5F 4B F4 C5 A5`
Needed output: `0x04 0x5F 0x4B 0xF4 0xC5 0xA5`

I am trying to use `hexcode[i] = ("0x%.2X", (unsigned char)c);` to store it correctly and it still only seems to return the last two chars without the 0x.

I have also tried `hexcode[i] = '0x' + (unsigned char)c;` and looked into functions like `sprintf`.

Can anyone help me get my desired output? Is it even possible?

Full program -

```
    #include <iostream>

unsigned char hexcode[99999] = { 0 };

//Takes exes hex and place it into unsigned char array
int hexcoder(std::string file) {
    FILE *sf; //executable file
    int i, c;

    sf = fopen(file.c_str(), "rb");
    if (sf == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file.", file.c_str());
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0;;i++) {
        if ((c = fgetc(sf)) == EOF) break;
        hexcode[i] = ("0x%.2X", (unsigned char)c);

        //Print for debug
        std::cout << std::hex << static_cast<int>(hexcode[i]) << ' ';
    }

}

int main()
{
    std::string file = "shuffle.exe"; // test exe to pass to get hex
    hexcoder(file);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How can you have `0x4G` as a hex number?  Valid digits are `0123456789ABCDEF`.  There is no `G` in hexadecimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you want to dump a file in hex format. So maybe it's something like the following code you are looking for.
Note that `hexcode` is changed to data type `char` instead of `unsigned char` such that it can be handled as a string containing printable characters.

```
int hexcoder(std::string file) {
    FILE *sf; //executable file
    int i, c;

    sf = fopen(file.c_str(), "rb");
    if (sf == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s.", file.c_str());
        return 1;
    }

    char hexcode[10000];
    char* wptr = hexcode;
    for (i = 0;;i++) {
        if ((c = fgetc(sf)) == EOF) break;

        wptr += sprintf(wptr,"0x%02X ", c);            
    }
    *wptr = 0;

    std::cout << hexcode;

    return 0;
}
```

BTW: for printing out a value in hex format one could as well use...

```
printf("0x%2X ", c)
```

or

```
std::cout << "0x" << std::hex << std::setw(2) << std::setfill('0') << std::uppercase << c << " ";
```

Note that the latter requires `#include <iomanip>`.

But - in order to not change the semantics of your code too much - I kept the `hexcode`-string as target.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! My goal is to actually store it in that format in the char array. I have tried your method and I am getting an exception error - Exception thrown at 0x76F6FF33 (ntdll.dll) in ConsoleApplication7.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00204556. Thanks again!

Comment: It's very likely that the array length is exceeded (for sure if the file size of your exe > 2000 bytes). Either increase the size of `hexcode` such that it can hold `(filesize * 5) +1` bytes, or use a dynamic data structure for hexcode, e.g. a `string` or a `stringstream`. Don't hesitate to ask if something is still unclear.

Comment: Working now. Thank you very much.